# Link-time optimization-enabled techniques and patterns?

Tags: c, optimization

Link-time optimization (LTO) (a.k.a. unity build) is included in GCC 4.5 or later and other compilers have similar optimization passes. Doesn't this make certain code patterns much more viable than before?

For example, for maximum performance a "module" of C code often needs to expose its guts. Does LTO make this obsolete? What code patterns are now viable that were not before?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that LTO is simply an optimization, but not necessarily one that obviates the need for documentation of implemenation ("exposing the guts") of any module. Whole languages have been written to that effect; I do not think C will have that need removed from it soon, or perhaps ever.

From [the description of the LTO feature in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization):

> Link Time Optimization (LTO) gives GCC the capability of dumping its
>   internal representation (GIMPLE) to disk, so that all the different
>   compilation units that make up a single executable can be optimized as
>   a single module. This expands the scope of inter-procedural
>   optimizations to encompass the whole program (or, rather, everything
>   that is visible at link time).

[From the announcement of LTO's inclusion into gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-10/msg00060.html):

> The result should, in principle, execute faster but our IPA cost
>   models are still not tweaked for LTO.  We've seen speedups as well as
>   slowdowns in benchmarks (see the LTO testers at
>   http://gcc.opensuse.org/).